# Error TypeScript compilation failed error is thrown when TestCafe test is executed through VS Code

Tags: typescript, testcafe

I have a test that runs perfectly on TestCafe studio but throws the following error when the same test is executed through VS Code.

VS Code :Version: 1.73.1 (Universal)Commit
TypeScript: Version 4.9.3
OS : macOs Monterey 12.6
TestCafe extensions

```
Debugger attached.
The "browsers" option from the configuration file will be ignored.
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to the following error:

Error: TypeScript compilation failed.
Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (99, 68): Type expected.
Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (99, 77): '}' expected.
Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (99, 78): Declaration or statement expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (99, 80): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (101, 33): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (101, 48): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (102, 8): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (108, 22): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (108, 23): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (108, 33): ')' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (110, 26): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (110, 27): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (110, 35): Declaration or statement expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (110, 37): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (110, 44): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (114, 52): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (114, 53): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (114, 60): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (114, 70): Declaration or statement expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (118, 28): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (118, 29): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (118, 53): '(' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (118, 55): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (118, 62): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (224, 41): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (233, 31): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (259, 62): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (355, 49): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts 
.....
.....
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (1187, 33): ';' expected.
/Documents/web_automation/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts (1255, 1): Unterminated template literal.



Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

What could be the reason?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because VS Code has [its own default TS options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_formatting). The easiest way to avoid this error is to create your own `tsconfig.json` and type `{}` in it. After that, it will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have created a ```tsconfig.json``` and placed it in the root folder. It is not working even after restarting the VS Code. Tried with the  --ts-config-path too. Tried with ``` "compilerOptions": {
        "typescript": { "configPath": "./tsconfig.json"}
   }``` too. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please share a simple sample where I can do this. You can share your sample [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) if you don't want to send it in this thread.

Comment: It was noted that the issue with the older version of TestCafe caused the issue. Upgrading to the latest solved the issue.